# How to change the media upload path in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How can change the path for files from lets say: /wp-content/uploads/2018/04/FILE

To /FILE or /file_type/FILE

Is there any simple way without affecting the database and running into problems along the way?

And without losing the changes with the next update?

Thank you :)

Comment: You can create a rule in `.htaccess`

Comment: define('UPLOADS', 'files'); in wp-config

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the default media upload location, you need to edit the wp-config.php file located in the root directory of your WordPress installation. If you want upload directory to be wp-content/files then you will need to place the following code in wp-config.php.

```
define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/'.'files' );
```

If you want the upload directory to be outside wp-content, like http://www.example.com/files/ then you need to set upload path in wp-config.php like this:

```
define( 'UPLOADS', ''.'files' );
```